# Creating a new user on Azure VM that is not part of an Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

How do I create a new user that can login to my Azure VM as an administrator?  My top google search result mentions Active Directory.  This particular machine is not on a domain.  I tried creating the user under computer management and I get an unknown error and there is nothing helpful in the Event Viewer.

I also tried adding a user from the Azure Portal under Access Control for my VM instance and see a message that reads "No Virtual Machines In This Subscription Can Be Assigned Access".

Comment: I can create a new user under "Local Users and Groups" then add this user into "Administrators" group on my workgroup Azure VM successfully. What is your specific error?

Comment: For some reason, it worked today.  Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a user under the computer management worked for me

Answer (score -3):

I just done it by login to the VM where I want the another account:

NB: these instruction are for Win Server 2012 R2 based VMs

1. login to the VM by using an existing admin account
2. Hit start and type "create an account"
3. click on Add a user account
4. Enter username & password (password should met the complexity requirements)
5. Hit next and you will see a message stating the user has been created
6. if required, the account type can be changed to admin

   - Hit search and type Change Account Type
   - choose the account
   - select administrator or standard
   - hit change account type
   - and you are done :)